# Liferay + Geoserver

Tags: liferay, geoserver

I've geoserver 2.1.3 and Liferay 6 ga1 the problem is .. I'm using 2 different ports for each , geoserver running on 8080 and Liferay running on 8082. This is a waste since its possible to have geoserver running in Liferay , right? 
The problem is

How can I integrate GeoServer with Liferay?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Liferay is just a web application, just like any other regular web application is. Don't let yourself be tricked by the fact that you can download tomcat bundles: You can also download the WAR archive (and a few global dependency files, for the global classpath) and deploy them to any appserver (e.g. tomcat).

It's [well documented](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/lp-6-1-ugen11-installing-liferay-on-an-existing-application-server-0) in the User Guide. (Linking just the first relevant chapter, read through the following ones as well, choose your appserver/servlet container.)

Comment: I've deployed the geoserver but now when i add the geoserver portlet to a page it displays nothing... do you know what can be ?

Comment: More details please... Did you deploy geoserver on the same server as Liferay is running on? Is it running standalone (try without the portlet)? Is there anything in the logs? What exactly did you do (might be too much for a comment - just edit your question in that case)