# How to deploy geoserver war in Liferay portal 6.2

Tags: java, tomcat, liferay, geoserver

I am trying to deploy Geoserver war in Liferay portal 6.2 and I followed these steps :

1. Edit Geoserver war in netbeans in order to update web.xml to version 2.4 specifications.
2. Import Geoserver war to Liferay portal 6.2.

The problems is : When I try display Geoserver portlet, Nothing is diplayed and I get this message in log :

> no mapping found for http request with uri in dispatcherservlet with name 'dispatcher'.

Please any help ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Liferay + Geoserver](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12178238/liferay-geoserver)

Answer (score 0):

This [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/28232/geoserver-in-liferay) seems to indicate that you should drop the war file into liferay's tomcat folder.

Comment: I tried to drop the war file into liferay's tomcat folder, but no Geoserver portlet is created.